# How to Read a file word by word and use those words to grep in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read a file word by word and i want to use each word in that text file as an input to grep.
to read the file word by word i have used the following code

```
for word in $(<filename)
do
echo "$word"
done
```

now when I replaced

```
echo "$word"
```

with

```
grep -i "$word"
```

I'm not getting any output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what worked for me

```
while read line
do    
output=`grep -i "$line" /filepath/*`
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "$line present in file : $output"
 fi
done <filename
```

Comment: This doesn't use `line` for anything, and rather inexplicably only searches trough dot files in `/filepath/`.  The backticks and explicit `$?` comparison are antipatterns, but merely add bad smell, not incorrect behavior.  Changing `word` to `"$line"` would nominally fix this, but just `while read line; do grep -i "$line" /filepath/*; done <filename` would be simpler and more elegant.

Comment: @triplee as i had mentioned i wanted to do a word by word search of the contents in the file hence $word and .* was as per my requirement.I should have changed it before i gave the answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were the OP.  It's still not clear what the file is useful for here -- you just grep for the literal string `word` again and again, once for each line in the input file.  If the word is found in multiple files, the "human readable" output won't be, so just printing the output from `grep` directly would make more sense.

Comment: as i have told in my previous comment.It was an application specific answer.the word that i'm using to `grep` is present exactly in one file hence the answer @tripleee

Comment: So you only have a single line in `filename` and you don't care what's in it?  Or you know it contains `word` and nothing else?

Comment: its just one line in the file name and i know it contains around 1000 words.each word is being used as a key to find the file which contains it

Comment: I assumed that that is your intention but the code you have posted here doesn't do that.

Comment: I'm sure you managed to solve your individual problem to your own satisfaction, but look again at the code you posted here as an answer; it only works correctly for the very specific case when the file of words only contains the single literal word "word", and not for the more general problem you describe in the question.

Comment: @triplee now i get what you are saying.The thing is i'm not actually performing grep for `word` the word is a variable which contains different "words".I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Even though code edits on StackOverflow are generally not recommended, I have submitted an edit to your code. I hope you will review it, and change it if there is something which is still incorrect and unclear. But in order for this answer to be at all useful for future readers, the code in the answer should do what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

The following will read the file word by word and apply `grep` using the read word as input:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        grep -i "<REGULAR_EXPRESSION_HERE>" "$word"
    done
done < filename
```

Comment: what should be the regular expression.since i do not have any other specific information and when i tried to run it without the regular expression i'm not getting any o/p

Comment: `"<REGULAR EXPRESSION>"` is a pattern that you use to filter/search inside an input (in the case of the answer, the input is the content of `word`). Can you please tell what are you trying to achieve by using `grep` in word? What is you expected output?

Comment: I'm actually trying to find the files in the directory that contain the word that i have recovered from the text file.@anishsane @higuaro

Comment: Downvote: This assumes the file contains names of files, not expressions to search for.

Comment: ... in which case `xargs -a filename grep -i "<REGULAR EXPRESSION HERE>"` would be a somewhat more parsimonious way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting any output is that `grep` expects two arguments.  If you leave out the filename argument, it will wait for you to type in the text to grep from; it is reading standard input.  (This is what allows you to use it in a pipeline, like `command | grep error`.)

Anyway, what you are attempting is already built into `grep`.  Just pass it the file of search expressions as an argument to `-f`.

```
grep -irf filename .
```

where `-r` says to search recursively through all the files in a directory and `.` is the current directory.

Note, however, that this will search for matches anywhere on a line.  If your input file contains `dog` then `grep` will find a match on lines which contain `dogmatic` or `endogenous`; and if it contains an empty line, it will match all lines in all files.  Maybe look at the `-w` and/or `-x` options (as well as perhaps `-F` to disarm any regex specials in the input) to address these issues.

Answer (score 0):

See if this serves your purpose:

```
$ grep -o "\S*" filename | grep -i "<your regex here>"
```

The first grep in the pipeline will flatten the file to one word per line. Then second grep will search those word for your regex.

Note: This answer assumes that the individual words in file are the data you want to grep in. If those are supposed to be interpreted as filenames, refer to [higuaro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29226165/793796).

Comment: i was wondering if you could help me with the regular expression since I'm new to this.

Comment: We are not clear about what exactly you want to do. Please clarify about what you are trying to do & your expected end result..

Comment: I'm actually trying to find the files in the directory that contain the word that i have recovered from the text file.@anishsane @higuaro